# Forest Admin - Display object on data list

Tags: mongoose, forestadmin

I have a problem with the display of objects with Forest Admin.

I have a field name : {fr: ..., en: ..., nl: ... } that doesn't display on the data list of my collection. Although when I'm on the details of any element in my collection, I can see the object Name with his properties.

Is it possible to display the object name with his properties on the data list ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Forest Admin doesn't display nested documents on the list view.

You'll have to use smart fields to make them visible on the list view.

See [this woodshop example](https://docs.forestadmin.com/woodshop/how-tos/display-edit-a-nested-document)

```
in models/users.js

const schema = mongoose.Schema({
  'person': {
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
  },
}, {
  timestamps: false,
});
```

```
in /forest/users.js

collection('users', {
  fields: [{
    field: 'firstname',
    type: 'String',
    // Display the firstname
    get: (user) => {
      return user.person.firstname;
    },
    // Edit the firstname
    set: ((user, value) => {
      if (!user.person) {
        user.person = {};
      }
      user.person.firstname = value;
    })
  }],
});
```